# xperia SP cant move apps to sd

Tags: sony-xperia-sp

currently i have xperia SP c5303 which is i know an outdated device but cannot change to a new phone at the moment... so the problem here is internal memory is too small and i need to move them to sd card... i've installed appMgr III and it says that the device doesn't enable users moving apps to the sd card. do note that i already root my device... the apps also tells that the manufacture had removed the function of moving apps to sd card... can I overcome this problem and change the manufacture settings? help me please because i've searched the available method but had not found one yet...

Comment: What version of Android do you have?  Are you rooted?  Have you tried link2sd?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to move apps to SD Memory card although the device is rooted. There are workarounds for swapping internal memory and external memory but it seems to be temporary (maybe until the next boot up I think). Flashing a custom rom is recommended from my side. Visit xdadevelopers website and find your device thread for more details.